# faces-config with from-outcome not being string (boolean) fails with NullPointerException

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, mojarra, faces-config

I've been using JSF 2.1 with `mojarra-2.1.20`, and I've configured in my `faces-config.xml` a navigation case like this:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/loggedOut.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{sessionManager.isLoggedIn}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The action is executed using [seam-faces `viewAction`](https://github.com/seam/faces/blob/develop/api/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/faces/component/UIViewAction.java) (similiar to JSF 2.2 new tag). All has been working fine.

Today I've upgraded to JSF 2.2 with `mojarra-2.2.6`, and browsing to the view `loggedOut.xhtml` stoped working. It throws this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findExactMatch(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getViewId(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:481)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getNavigationCase(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:149)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getNavigationCase(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.SeamPreNavigationHandler.getNavigationCase(SeamPreNavigationHandler.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.event.SeamPreNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(SeamPreNavigationHandler.java:57)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:381)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    ...
```

I have more navigations like this, and all of them fail in the same way. The only difference between this navigations and other cases and examples is that `from-outcome` value is a `boolean` and not a `String`. So my questions are:

- Should `from-outcome`'s fail when it is not a `String`?

  - If so, should not fail with a more "readable" message?
  - Else, is a `mojara` bug?
- Version 2.1 was wrong then?

I know how to "fix it": using a `{dummyAction.execute}` and checking the boolean in the `<if>` tag. But I prefered to execute the real action and not 2 differents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting [@glassfish](https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/webtier/archive/2014-06/message/0), and doing some testing and debugging, I found that the real cause is the deprecated thirdaparty CDI extension [seam-faces](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule).

As they extends the [`javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html), but the code is compiled against [JSF 2.1](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html), the method [`#getFlowHandler`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html#getFlowHandler%28%29) returns always `null`.