# Seam in JSF 2.2 causes java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome

Tags: jsf, seam, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

I am trying to run my application on WildFly8.2, which was build by using Jboss 5.1.I migrated my entire application and able to see the login page. But while navigating to JSF pages, it is throwing the below exception.

My old application is build on JSF 1.2

```
2015-07-15 14:49:02,108 INFO          [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1)     Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1 20140822-1131 for context '/booking'
    2015-07-15 14:49:03,303 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /booking
2015-07-15 14:49:03,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "booking.ear" (runtime-name : "booking.ear")
2015-07-15 14:49:03,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190/management
2015-07-15 14:49:03,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)     JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
2015-07-15 14:49:03,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 15104ms - Started 637 of 711 services (124 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2015-07-15 14:50:12,989 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter] (default task-1) Initializing filter: org.jboss.seam.web.redirectFilter
2015-07-15 14:50:12,993 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter] (default task-1) Initializing filter: org.jboss.seam.web.exceptionFilter
2015-07-15 14:50:12,995 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter] (default task-1) Initializing filter: org.jboss.seam.web.multipartFilter
2015-07-15 14:50:12,996 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter] (default task-1) Initializing filter: org.jboss.seam.web.loggingFilter
2015-07-15 14:50:12,998 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter] (default task-1) Initializing filter: org.jboss.seam.web.identityFilter
2015-07-15 14:50:20,699 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions] (default task-13) handled and logged exception: javax.servlet.ServletException
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1341) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findWildCardMatch(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:661) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getViewId(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:483) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:190) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(SeamNavigationHandler.java:49) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
  ... 42 more
```

I am suspecting that this issue is because of my jsf or rich faces jars, however I am looking into this issue.

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the combination Seam 2.3.x and JSF 2.2. You need to either [migrate Seam](http://seamframework.org/) to [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/), which is JSF 2.2 compatible, or to [downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly) Mojarra 2.2.x in WildFly to 2.1.x.

The technical problem is, Seam used [an `Application` implementation](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.1.Final/api/org/jboss/seam/jsf/SeamApplication.html) which didn't properly extend from [`javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html) and thus  [it had to manually implement/delegate all `Application` methods to the wrapped application](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.seam/jboss-seam/2.3.1.Final/org/jboss/seam/jsf/SeamApplication.java#SeamApplication). In case of Seam 2.3.x, all those methods were based on JSF 2.1. In JSF 2.2, a new method [`getFlowHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getFlowHandler()) was added to `Application`, which wasn't properly delegated by Seam and thus returned `null`, causing all the trouble further down in the chain relying on it not being `null`. If Seam guys had properly extended from `ApplicationWrapper` instead of hardcoding all delegate methods for a specific JSF version, then it would flawlessly have worked across JSF versions.

#### See also:

- [Weld in JSF 2.2 causes java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/75)
  (exactly same problem with older Weld versions)
- [SWF in JSF 2.2 causes java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605401/swf-in-jsf-2-2-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-applicatio)
  (exactly same problem with older Spring WebFlow versions)

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the root cause, the issue is because of the jar version,downgraded the jar version to  2.1.29-jbossorg-1 and it worked for me.

For doing this add the jar to          ${JBOSS_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/com/sun/jsf-impl/main/
    and update module.xml (available in same path)
 "resource-root" tag to point to the new file name.

Ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261071?sr=inbox&ru=123215

Comment: why downgrade to 2.1.29? Why not try to fix the problem since you are migrating