# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.jboss.seam.pdf.DocumentStorePhaseListener.beforePhase after migrating Seam 2.3.1 project from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.x

Tags: jsf, pdf, seam

I am working on migrating my application from Jboss 5.1.0 GA to WildFly 8.2.0. As part of this migration I migrated few technologies with new versions

- JSF 1.2 to 2.0
- Richfaces 3.3.3
- Hibernate 4.0.1
- Jboss Seam 2.3.1

I successfully deployed my application on WildFly 8.2.0 and able to load the log-in page.

When I am trying to log-in into my application, I am getting the below Exception.

```
19:51:30,851 SEVERE [javax.faces.webapp] (default task-3) java.lang.NullPointerException caught during beforePhase() processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=null
19:51:30,874 SEVERE [javax.faces.webapp] (default task-3) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.seam.pdf.DocumentStorePhaseListener.beforePhase(DocumentStorePhaseListener.java:35) [jboss-seam-pdf.jar:2.0.0.GA]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at com.project.session.projectReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(projectReplyHeaderFilter.java:59) [project-ejb.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
```

I am suspecting that there is an issue while rendering the JSF page, but it was working as expected on Jboss 5.1.0 GA with JSF 1.2

Comment: Have you verified if Seam 2.3.1 is JSF 2.2 compatible?

Comment: Wait, your stack trace mentions JSF API 2.2.8 and JSF impl 2.1.29 which is obviously a version conflict. What version exactly are you trying to target? And how exactly did you try to downgrade WildFly's builtin Mojarra 2.2.8 to Mojarra 2.1.29? That part also doesn't look good.

Comment: I have verified with small PoC, seam 2.3.1 is working on wildfly 8.2.0 which contains JSF 2.2

Comment: I'd as first step cleanup that classpath pollution of Mojarra 2.1.29 libraries somewhere in your webapp and then retry with stock Mojarra 2.2.8 as provided by WildFly.

Comment: I have tried with 2.2.8 and getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jboss.seam.ui.handler.CommandButtonParameterComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig) while starting the server itself

Comment: Well, if that happened on the PoC without 2.1.x libraries, then Seam 2.3.1 is clearly not compatible with JSF 2.2. You'd need to downgrade WildFly's stock JSF 2.2.8 to JSF 2.1.x as per the instructions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly

Comment: I had a deja vu and stumbled upon a question you previously asked but never accepeted nor gave any feedback on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427272/seam-in-jsf-2-2-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-applicati Seam 2.3.1 is definitely not compatible with JSF 2.2.

Comment: I refereed your answer, but it worked in my PoC. So I assumed that JSF 2.2 will work on Seam 2.3.1.  My next question is What version of JSF does Seam 2.3.1 supports?, because I can't migrate my seam to WELD or others.

Comment: My apology, I downgraded my JSF to 2.1.29 in my PoC. So it will not support. I will try to downgrade my JSF API to 2.1.29 and will see the result

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue got resolved after downgrading my JSF API to 2.1.29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seam 2.3.1 is not compatible with JSF 2.2. It's basically succeeded by [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/).

If you can't migrade to DeltaSpike, then your best bet is to downgrade Mojarra 2.2.x in WildFly to latest 2.1.x version using the instructions detailed in this answer: [Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly). Just substitute "Upgrade" with "Downgrade" over all place :)